# sending raw binary using tcp in erlang

Tags: tcp, binary, erlang

I have a basic client server in erlang which uses tcp.

How does one send the actual binary data from a file to the client who requested it?

How is the file sent in pieces?

I have this code

`{ok, Socket} =
            gen_tcp:connect({Ip}, 2345,
                            [binary, {packet, 4}]),`

Does this {packet, 4} handle the data size that is send both ways?

Also, how does the client receive data and then do something with it? Like save it to a file?

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of questions here. You might be better off breaking it up into smaller questions. You might also benefit from this: http://20bits.com/articles/erlang-a-generalized-tcp-server/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes - `{packet, 4}` will cause erlang to require a packet frame of a 4 byte unsigned big endian integer length value on receive, and will emit one before each packet of data sent.

You can send data on the socket by calling `gen_tcp:send(Socket, Data)`. This will do something like:

```
RawData = iolist_to_binary(Data),
Length = byte_size(RawData),
Packet = <<Length:32/big-unsigned-integer, RawData/binary>>,
send(Socket, Packet).
```

So provided your file is less than 4Gb, you could send it by doing

```
{ok, File} = file:read_file(FileName),
gen_tcp:send(Socket, File).
```

On the receiving end:

```
File = gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0).
```

You'll get the complete file because of the `{packet, 4}` framing.

Comment: Thanks. If the incoming data is part of a file, in no specific order(torrent's BITFIELD) and I write to file after a certain buffer or chunks received, how would this effect the {packet, someValue}?Also with File = gen_tcp:recv(Socket, 0) will this file be stored in memory and can then be written to disk when the entire file is received?

Comment: `Packet, 4` gives you framing only. Bittorrent is its own protocol which you'd need to implement separately (and because bittorrent specifies something other than `{packet, 4}` framing, you'll end up using `{packet, raw}`). You could look at an erlang inmplementation for examples of how to do this -- try http://github.com/jlouis/etorrent/tree/